# Finding way with BFS

Tags: c++, c++11, breadth-first-search

I am trying to find a shortest way using BFS alghoritm. e.g
i add a points to map

```
     add("berlin",london")
     add("budapest","london")
     add("london","glassgow")
     add("budapest","moscow")
     find("berlin",moscow") // should return berlin , london , budapest,moscow
```

I have defined  a queue

```
struct node {
    string info;
    node *next;
};
/*----------------------------------------------------*/
class Queue {
    private:
        node *front;
        node *rear;
    public:
        Queue();
        ~Queue();
        bool isEmpty();
        void enqueue(string );
        string dequeue();
        void display();
        bool find(string);
};
/*----------------------------------------------------*/
void Queue::display(){
    node *p = new node;
    p = front;
    if(front == NULL){
        cout<<"Nothing to Display" << endl;
    }else{
        while(p!=NULL){
            cout<<p->info << endl;
            p = p->next;
        }
    }
}
/*----------------------------------------------------*/
Queue::Queue() {
    front = NULL;
    rear = NULL;
}
/*----------------------------------------------------*/
Queue::~Queue() {
    delete front;
}
/*----------------------------------------------------*/
void Queue::enqueue(string data) {
    node *temp = new node();
    temp->info = data;
    temp->next = NULL;
    if(front == NULL){
        front = temp;
    }else{
        rear->next = temp;
    }
    rear = temp;
}
/*----------------------------------------------------*/
string Queue::dequeue() {
    node *temp = new node();
    string value;
    if(front == NULL){
        cout<<"Queue is Emtpty" << endl;
    }else{
        temp = front;
        value = temp->info;
        front = front->next;
        delete temp;
    }
    return value;
}
/*----------------------------------------------------*/
bool Queue::isEmpty() {
    return (front == NULL);
}
bool Queue::find( string name){
    node *temp = rear;
    while( temp != nullptr ){
        if( temp -> info == name){
            return true;
        }
        temp = temp -> next;
    }
    return false;
}
```

and tried to implement bfs

```
class Graph {
    private:
        map< string , map<string, int >> graf;
    public:
        Graph(){};
        ~Graph(){};
        bool isConnected(string , string );
        void addEdge    (string one , string two);
        void BFS(string ,string);
};
/*----------------------------------------------------*/
bool Graph::isConnected(string one , string two){
    return (graf[one][two] == 1 || graf[two][one] == 1 );
}
/*----------------------------------------------------*/
void Graph::addEdge( string one , string two){
    graf [one][two] = graf[two][one] = 1;
}

/*----------------------------------------------------*/
void Graph::BFS(string s , string m){
    Queue one;
    map<string , bool> check;

    vector<string> path;
    for( auto &x : graf){
        check[x.first] = false;
    }

    check[s] = true;
    one.enqueue(s);
    path.push_back(s);

    string tmp = one.dequeue();
    for( auto &x: graf){
        if( isConnected(tmp , x.first)  && !check[x.first] ){
            one.enqueue(x.first);
            check[x.first] = true;
            path.push_back(x.first);
            if(x.first == m){
                break;
            }
        }
    }

    for( auto &x: path )
        cout << x << " ";
}
```

to find correct "towns" and store them for printing. The problem is , this does print ALL posibilities not just correct way. e.g in case a mentioned earlier it also find "budapest - london " and print it. I know the problem is that i enqueue every "town" in the way but fail to find a way how to check its correctness.

I am not exactly sure how i can find the ONLY ( shorest ) way. I recently found out about this alghoritm and cant get him work. How can i improve this alghoritm i implemented to behave in such way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of puting nodes in a "path", you can keep the "parent" of each node. I've changed your code and used `check` variable as the parent data structure.

If a parent is not set, then is not checked, therefore the if statement is also checking to see if the parent is set.

At the end, you only need to go through parents, until you reach the destination.

Please also note than I changed the BFS to start from destination. I did it because otherwise iterating back from the last node to the fist node would return the reverse of the path you need.

Here's the code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <map>

using namespace std;

struct node {
    string info;
    node *next;
};
/*----------------------------------------------------*/
class Queue {
    private:
        node *front;
        node *rear;
    public:
        Queue();
        ~Queue();
        bool isEmpty();
        void enqueue(string );
        string dequeue();
        void display();
        bool find(string);
};
/*----------------------------------------------------*/
void Queue::display(){
    node *p = new node;
    p = front;
    if(front == NULL){
        cout<<"Nothing to Display" << endl;
    }else{
        while(p!=NULL){
            cout<<p->info << endl;
            p = p->next;
        }
    }
}
/*----------------------------------------------------*/
Queue::Queue() {
    front = NULL;
    rear = NULL;
}
/*----------------------------------------------------*/
Queue::~Queue() {
    delete front;
}
/*----------------------------------------------------*/
void Queue::enqueue(string data) {
    node *temp = new node();
    temp->info = data;
    temp->next = NULL;
    if(front == NULL){
        front = temp;
    }else{
        rear->next = temp;
    }
    rear = temp;
}
/*----------------------------------------------------*/
string Queue::dequeue() {
    node *temp = new node();
    string value;
    if(front == NULL){
        cout<<"Queue is Emtpty" << endl;
    }else{
        temp = front;
        value = temp->info;
        front = front->next;
        delete temp;
    }
    return value;
}
/*----------------------------------------------------*/
bool Queue::isEmpty() {
    return (front == NULL);
}
bool Queue::find( string name){
    node *temp = rear;
    while( temp != nullptr ){
        if( temp -> info == name){
            return true;
        }
        temp = temp -> next;
    }
    return false;
}

class Graph {
    private:
        map< string , map<string, int >> graf;
    public:
        Graph(){};
        ~Graph(){};
        bool isConnected(string , string );
        void addEdge    (string one , string two);
        void BFS(string ,string);
};
/*----------------------------------------------------*/
bool Graph::isConnected(string one , string two){
    return (graf[one][two] == 1 || graf[two][one] == 1 );
}
/*----------------------------------------------------*/
void Graph::addEdge( string one , string two){
    graf [one][two] = graf[two][one] = 1;
}

/*----------------------------------------------------*/
void Graph::BFS(string s , string m){
    Queue one;
    map<string , string> check;

    for( auto &x : graf){
        check[x.first] = "-";
    }

    check[m] = "";
    one.enqueue(m);

    while (!one.isEmpty())
    {
        string tmp = one.dequeue();
        if(tmp == s){
            string c = tmp;
            while (c != m) {
                cout << c << " ";
                c = check[c];
            }
            cout << c << endl;
            return;
        }
        for( auto &x: graf){
            if( isConnected(tmp , x.first)  && check[x.first] == "-" ){
                one.enqueue(x.first);
                check[x.first] = tmp;
            }
        }
    }

}

int main()
{
    Graph g;
    g.addEdge("berlin","london");
    g.addEdge("budapest","london");
    g.addEdge("london","glassgow");
    g.addEdge("budapest","moscow");
    g.BFS("berlin","moscow");
    g.addEdge("london", "moscow");
    g.BFS("berlin","moscow");
    return 0;
}
```

And here's the output. The first one is w/o "london"->"moscow" edge, and the second is with that edge added to the graph.

```
berlin london budapest moscow
berlin london moscow
```